# Microsoft.Threading.Tasks not found

Tags: c#, .net

I have made a dll that wraps around some Google operations. With my first test drive it worked perfectly, but now in a real program, I get a weird assembly reference problem:

```
FileNotFoundException was unhandled
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Det går inte att hitta filen.
```

I have heard of System.Threading.Tasks (and am "using" it), but where does Microsoft.Threading.Tasks come in? The exception occurs at the last row of the snippet below.

```
Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.Groups allGroupsResp = null;
var req = DirectoryService.Groups.List();
req.Domain = _settings.Domain;
allGroupsResp = req.Execute();
```

And there is no Microsoft.Threading.Tasks in the assembly list.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566123/cannot-load-system-threading-tasks-assembly-using-google-calendar-api

Comment: The thing is that I AM referencing System.Threading.Tasks. But it looks for Microsoft.Threading.Tasks. They are not the same, or?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you're using the [Google API .Net Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Build). I suggest using Nuget to install the assemblies as described on the linked page. However, if you download the source, the `Microsoft.Threading.Task` assmeblies are included and so it seems the code your calling is trying to access those assemblies.

You could manually move that assembly into your directory but I'd usually opt for the `Nuget` method unless you need to be using a particular build.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Google API's, that I have added with NuGet.

If I download what source? Is Microsoft.Threading.Tasks not part of the standard .NET 4.5 distribution?

Comment: The link I posted is the project's page. In the `downloads` section ([here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Downloads)), you can download the binary, source, and samples. The binaries doesn't seem to contain the assembly but the source does.

Comment: Quite right you are! I only looked in the assemblies list in visual studio before, and now that you made me look in the downloaded files by NuGet, it was there. Adding the file to my ILMerge solved the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

This is what worked for me:

Open the NuGet console via the Tools menu > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console

From the console type in: update-package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -reinstall

After that, you may be prompted to re-start Visual Studio to finish uninstalling the package. Once you re-start, the package should be re-installed and everything should work.

Comment: yep !! Microsoft.bcl.Async from Nuget Package Manager resolves .. : )

Comment: i just had to install the nugetpackage microsoft.bcl.async package and it fixed it

Comment: Thanks man. You saved me. After two years this answer is still helping. I was deleted System.Threading.Tasks reference and this was dependancy for Firebird Ado client.

Comment: I'm glad it's still useful. :)

Answer (score 3):

I expect you are using the "google-api-dotnet-client". Microsoft.Threading.Tasks is a dll used by this client according to google code:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/ThirdParty/Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll

You probably just have to move this file into your bin directory.

Comment: This was the problem yes! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` nuget package!

(if you are using `Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2` with `UWP` app)

Comment: Explicitly, in Package Manager Console, type:
Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Answer (score 0):

There could be several problems - the first one you project where you've referenced this dll is not targeted to .Net4 or you just have not installed .Net4 framework on your box.

Comment: Both the dll I reference and the referencing project are targetting .NET Framework 4.5. And I do have .NET 4.5 installed on my box. I have worked with .NET on this computer in VS2012 with 4.5 applications since april.

Comment: Does dcastro's suggestion works for you? Looks like this is one of the possible solutions of assembly binding problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.PDB not being found.

Found the solution here: [Cannot find .cs files for debugging .NET source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320257/cannot-find-cs-files-for-debugging-net-source-code)

TL;DR: VS was trying to debug the .NET framework and I was missing the debug files. But I did not actually need to debug the .NET so i did:
***Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable just my Code***