# Visual Studio Mac debugger -- "FileStream.cs not found"

Tags: macos, debugging, visual-studio-mac

When I attempt to debug a unit test on VS Mac, I see the following:

[image]

In the solution options, I don't see anything about locations to find source files. And I'm certainly not interested in disassembly.

I did try using version control to move the code to a PC. There I could debug with no problems. I also found [Cannot find .cs files for debugging .NET source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320257/cannot-find-cs-files-for-debugging-net-source-code), which appears to be similar, but not Mac-oriented, and the menus are different on VS Mac, so I can't try the answer from that question.

How can I get it to debug on VS Mac?