# Visual Studio 2015 debugging not working.Error:methodbase.cs not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I use Visual studio 2015.

I put breakpoints in `Login(Post) Action` method and ran the project. Continue with F11 then error:

> methodbase.cs not found

or

> realproxy.cs not found

I tried

```
Tool>>Options>>Debugging>>Symbol>>Enable Just My Code
```

but it did nothing.

Comment: Hi Mustafa, without your code you are testing we can't reproduce your problem. Please edit question and paste it in. Version of VS15 comes in handy as for 32bit or 64bit win version.. Can you also post comeplete error. Use formatting (see ? at the textbox you paste info).

Comment: Hi, please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi friend, could you share the code where throw the exception? Not getting your entire error message, but it seems like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320257/cannot-find-cs-files-for-debugging-net-source-code). Check if it helps. If not, please share more details.THX:)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that you're debugging .net source code.

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2015). It describes the walkthrough in details.

Apart from `Tool>>Options>>Debugging>>Symbol>>Enable Just My Code`, you also need to `enable .NET Framework source stepping` and `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable source server support`and so on **before selecting 'Just My Code'**. Please follow the steps in the document to make it work.

> If you're not trying to debugging .net source code.

Then try Tools=>Import and Export Settings=>Reset all settings to reset, close and open the VS to check if it helps. Also, if you're not trying to debug the code from .net source, try using [step over(F10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017#step-over-code-to-skip-functions), which is similar to step into but will skip the functions if you don't want to look into them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did but not working. I solved the my problem. Updated Visual Studio 2017 and worked

Comment: @MUSTAFAYAVUZ Well, you can add it as a answer(workaround).