# Debugger asking for datetime.cs source though it shjouldn't based on the solutions properties

Tags: c#, datetime, debugging, dll, external

I'm trying to get DLL debugging to work and I'm having some weird issues.

When I'm tyring to "step into" the DLL method that is being called I get the following [popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC2ku.png) asking for the source of DateTime.cs. But the debugger should not look for these sources because it says this in the solution [properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbKrr.png).

The code is like the following:

```
var a = ExternalDLLClass.MethodThatWorks(DateTime.Now);
```

The program itself works fine, but I don't understand this behaviour and it blocks my debugging.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320257/cannot-find-cs-files-for-debugging-net-source-code

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I solved it by going to tools -> Options, go to Debugging and then "Enable just my code".