# WebApplicationContext.cs not found, System.Web.HttpException: Request not available in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, spring.net

I am running a .NET website using IIS-7 from Visual Studio 2019. I am running into the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/imH8t.jpg

I made sure that all of the projects that are part of the solution have the same target framework version (in this case, this is .NET 4.5.2).

Also, the file itself seems to be part of the Spring.Web Assembly, so I made sure that all the projects are referencing the same version of this assembly.

Not sure what screenshots to share other than the error itself, so please let me know what else will be helpful in answering this question.

Comment: Look at the call stack of the exception. Have you been doing async work and then tried to access some data regarding request context? The request is only available on the thread that the request is handled on.

Comment: An exception occurs inside that class, probably because you're using it wrong. Visual Studio apparently is configured to look up the source of that class. Disable that (["Just My Code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320257/cannot-find-cs-files-for-debugging-net-source-code)), or continue debugging until you receive the actual exception.

Comment: @CodeCaster How would I disable this behavior? Also, when I continue, I seem to be getting another error: https://imgur.com/a/Y6BqQMj. The file described here ("Configdao.config") does not exist on my project. I tried just adding a temporary file named that, but it looks like it is not the only `.config` file missing. Should I be getting these files/generating them from somewhere in my project?

Comment: Such an exception comes from Spring.NET itself, so you need to refer to its documentation or ping its developers for assistance.