# Visual Studio: ScriptLoggingBuilderExtensions.cs not found when debugging

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I am using Visual Studio version 16.7.3 (latest) and recently came upon a problem.
I am creating an Azure Function, using .net Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.

Everything went fine until recently I got HTTP 500 errors. I went to check it out locally and placed some stopping points for the debug process. After a few lines of debugging I suddenly get a popup saying:

[image: ScriptLoggingBuilderExtensionError]

This has never popped up before. I did some Googling but none of the available fixes worked for me.
Anyone else experienced this before?

Thank you

Comment: [Does this solve your problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320257/cannot-find-cs-files-for-debugging-net-source-code)

Comment: It does not, unfortunately. I don't even have the option "enable just my code".
This are all my options:
https://i.imgur.com/hXe5CqQ.png

Answer (score 0):

For me, I've just added the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package, and it's working.