# How to find the source file in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, debugging, compiler-errors

What is a source file and how to locate it in my project?
Underlined directory doesn't exist anymore.

[image]

I tried these [Cannot find .cs files for debugging .NET source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320257/cannot-find-cs-files-for-debugging-net-source-code) soultions but they didn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to debug compiled code for which you don’t have the source?

Comment: @stuartd I guess you said it right but the .cs file is in the solution explorer, the project was built all right, I don't see why it is still looking for some App.cs ??

Comment: Make sure you are really executing the project that you intend to. Maybe the code that runs is an old version of your application?

Comment: check dependencies of the project.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?